# How to return parent function value if it returns a value, and if not, continue running the child function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, inheritance

I am trying to check if a parent function call returns a value, and if it does, return said value. Here is an example of the situation:

```
class ParentClass():

    @staticmethod
    def some_function(color):
        if (color == 'red'):
            return 1
        elif (color == 'blue'):
            return 2

class ChildClass()
    
    @staticmethod
    def some_function(color):
        super(ChildClass, ChildClass).some_function(color)
        if (color == 'green'):
            return 3
        elif (color == 'yellow'):
            return 4
```

I would like to return the value from the function call `super(ChildClass, ChildClass).some_function(color)` if it returns anything, but if not, continue with rest of the code in ChildClass' some_function.

My current solution is to replace the parent function call with:

```
    super_value = super(ChildClass, ChildClass).some_function(color)
    if super_value:
        return super_value
```

But I would like to find a better way to do this, if possible.

Comment: Your solution is about as good as it reasonably needs to be. Maybe change if super_value to explicit == None statement in case you want to return 0

Comment: Note that your solution will not return the super value if it's `0`. If you want to check if it returns a value use `if super_value is not None:`

Comment: "But I would like to find a better way to do this, if possible." better *in what way?*

Comment: I came up with another solution that works it does not matter if the parent or child function is called first. I removed the parent call from the top of the function and added
`else: return super(ChildClass, ChildClass).some_function(color)
`
at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
class ParentClass():

    @staticmethod
    def some_function(color):
        if (color == 'red'):
            return 1
        elif (color == 'blue'):
            return 2
        else:
            #what happens if else?
            return None
           

class ChildClass():
    
    @staticmethod
    def some_function(color):
        t =ParentClass.some_function # personal preference
        #t = super(ChildClass, ChildClass).some_function 
        if t(color) is not None:
           return t(color)
        elif (color == 'green'):
            return 3
        elif (color == 'yellow'):
            return 4
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: why call it twice???

Comment: Because I would like to embody it in one logical part, which works with the "color" parameter, don't think that this overhead in this case would break something ...

Comment: ... but why not just use a variable with a descriptive name for the result?